# cut off known substring sh

Tags: sh

How to cut off known substring from the string in sh? 
For example, I have string `"http://www.myserver.org/very/very/long/path/mystring"`
expression `"http://www.myserver.org/very/very/long/path/"` is known. How can I get "mystring"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g. using perl:

```
echo "http://www.myserver.org/very/very/long/path/mystring" | perl -pe 's|^http://www.myserver.org/very/very/long/path/(.*)$|\1|'
```

E.g. using sed:

```
echo "http://www.myserver.org/very/very/long/path/mystring" | sed 's|^http://www.myserver.org/very/very/long/path/\(.*\)$|\1|'
```

E.g. when the search string is held in a variable, here named `variable`. Use double quotes to expand the variable.

```
echo "http://www.myserver.org/very/very/long/path/mystring" | sed "s|^${variable}\(.*\)$|\1|"
```

Comment: Use double quotes around the expression so that variables are expanded. E.g. `sed "s|^${shorturl}\(.*\)$|\1|"`. Updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Tested under /bin/[dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell)

```
$ S="http://www.myserver.org/very/very/long/path/mystring" && echo ${S##*/}
mystring
```

where

```
S  is the variable-name
## remove largest prefix pattern
*/ upto the last slash
```

For further reading, search "##" in [man dash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash)

Some more illustrations:

```
$ S="/mystring/" ; echo ${S##*/}

$ S="/mystring" ; echo ${S##*/}
mystring
$ S="mystring" ; echo ${S##*/}
mystring
```